# Responsive HTML/CSS to Send Text Below Form

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive, overlap

I am working on creating a responsive log in page. I have section of text in a table to provide some quick information for users prior to them logging in. The problem is that when the screen/window size gets smaller, the log in form overlaps/covers the text. I would like for the text to move down below the login form when the screen shrinks, but I am not exactly sure how to do that. I was able to get the logo image at the top and the links menu to respond to size changes using "max-width" CSS properties, but cannot figure out how to move something to another part of the page. The HTML/CSS that I am working with is pasted below and I have attached a screenshot from my phone showing the overlap issue. I know the HTML/CSS isn't ideal, but I am having to do this in a very limited editor. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<p><img src="https://www.westga.edu/uwgonline/assets-uwgonline/pics/CourseDen.png" style="z-index: -1; margin: 0% 1.5%; max-width: 1100px; width: 90%; position: absolute; height: auto;" /></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table style="z-index: -1; opacity: 0.85; max-width: 100%; width: 50%; left: 35%; top: 380px; position: absolute;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 20px; background: #FFFFFF;">
                <p>
                    <span style="color: #000000;">
                    <span style="color: #000000;">
                        <em>Please note your password is the same as your <strong>UWG ID</strong> and is case sensitive.</em>
                    </span>
                    </span>
                </p>
                <strong><span style="color: #000000;">UWG Online Help Desk</span></strong>
                <br />
                <span style="color: #000000;">(M-F 8a-5p ET) 678-839-6248 or 1-855-933-8946</span>
                <br /><a href="mailto:online@westga.edu">online@westga.edu</a> &bull; <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="http://uwgonline.westga.edu/uwgonline/chat-with-us.php" target="_blank">Chat</a>
                <p><strong><span style="color: #000000;">24/7/365 D2L Help Center</span></strong>
                    <br /><span style="color: #000000;">Knowledge Base &amp; Live Support</span>
                    <br /><a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://D2Lhelp.view.usg.edu" target="_blank">https://D2Lhelp.view.usg.edu</a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr />
<table style="max-width: 100%; width: 99%; text-align: center; border: none; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;"><a href="https://uwgonline.westga.edu/uwg-online-contact-us.php" target="blank" style="color: #777777;">Help</a></td>
            <td style="width: 20%; border-left: 1px solid #D3D3D3;"><a href="https://uwgonline.westga.edu/uwg-online-student-help.php" target="blank" style="color: #777777;"> Resources </a></td>
            <td style="width: 20%; border-left: 1px solid #D3D3D3;"><a href="http://uwgonline.westga.edu/" target="blank" style="color: #777777;"> More Info</a></td>
            <td style="width: 20%; border-left: 1px solid #D3D3D3;"><a href="https://westga.view.usg.edu/d2l/systemCheck" target="blank" style="color: #777777;"> System Checker</a></td>
            <td style="width: 20%; border-left: 1px solid #D3D3D3;"><a href="https://go.view.usg.edu/" target="blank" style="color: #777777;"> eCampus, WebMBA, &amp; EU</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr />
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know much of front end stuff but whenever I feel the need of having a responsive layout, I prefer Bootstrap.

Comment: The problem is that I have to design this within our organizations Learning Management System (BrightSpace by D2L). The only thing I have is a text editor that acts like a very limited WYSIWYG editor with the option to view and edit the HTML directly. I don't have the option to build this out the "proper" way. If I did, I think I could figure it out, but getting it to work in this limited manner is difficult (to say the least).

Comment: I am unable to see login section with your code. Please post a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Unfortunately the login section is automatically added by the LMS and is not something I can see or edit until the changes are previewed/published. I'm trying to get the information from the browser's developer/inspector console, but it isn't quite working as easily as I hoped.

Comment: Seems the login window is positioned absolute. You could add a media query for small screen size, and overwrite the position of the login form (if you know it's class or id) to add it back to the dom. Can you access the rendered site in a normal browser?

Comment: @Sirence, I can pull the site up in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc and I can view the page source from those browsers.

Comment: When you open the site in Chrome, and then press F12, you can get the html and css of the login window. (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) Please add that to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem was to take the text that is getting stuck behind the login box and remove it's `position: absolute`. This put the login box below it. What we really wanted was the login box to the left of the text and only moved down below it when a screen/window was under a certain size, but because I cannot edit the login box, this is the solution that we decided was going to be the best for what we had access to edit. That you @Sirence for mentioning the `position: absolute` information in your comment!